# MvcHtmlString without Razor Encoding

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm writing a method that generating a javascript code and sending the razor view.
But razor view encoding this according to its head.Codes is below.

This is my method body, returning a mvchtmlstring:

```
StringBuilder scriptHtml = new StringBuilder();
        scriptHtml.Append("<script>");
        scriptHtml.Append(@"var {0} = {{
                    id: 'someText',
                    title: '{1}',

                 $(document).ready(function () {{
                       $.function({0});
                   }});");

        scriptHtml.Append("</script>");
var output = string.Format(scriptHtml.ToString(), this.Id, this.Title);
return MvcHtmlString.Create(output);
```

So now, its output is :

```
@&lt;script&gt;var tlyPageGuide,,&quot;direction&quot;:&quot;Right&quot;
```

Something like this growing with encoded.

That's what I want is the Razor should not change my code while cshtml is creating and I gotta get pure javascript code with rendered.

Note : I don't want to use Html.Raw() for the solution.I want to make this on server-side.

Comment: what do you mean "on server side"? All your Razor Views rendered on server side.

Comment: I mean, I don't want any additional Html.Raw() code in the view. I want to encode it on `return MvcHtmlString.Create(output)` or method body for example. By the way; Html.Raw() is working but I don't want to use it every time and every where when I'm invoking my method via Helper like this `@Html.Raw(Html.MyHelper.MyMethod())`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using partial view?

For instance: (this code may contain errors but you get the idea):

```
class MyScriptModel
{
  public string Id {get;set;}
  public string Title {get;set;}
}

//your partial view: my_partial.cshtml
@model MyScriptModel
//extracted from your string builder
<script>
        var @Model.Id = {{
                    id: 'someText',
                    title: '@Model.Title',

                 $(document).ready(function () {{
                       $.function(@Model.Id);
                   }});

</script>

//instantiate the model
var model = new MyScriptModel {Id="someid", Title="some title"};

//using your partial view
@Html.Partial("my_partial", model)
```